# Create an array of IPlImage in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

I am very new to OpenCV and I have the following question:

I understand that I can create an image using:

```
IplImage  *img
```

What i want is making a database of images. For example:

```
img[0]: will have image 1,
img[1]: will have image 2,
img[2]: will have image 3,
 etc...
```

How can i do such a thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `IplImage` is use for one image. So you can create a `IplImage *img = NULL` then allocate or fill it with different sources of images with for example:

```
img[0] = cvLoadImage(...);
```

Do not forget to release your images:

```
cvReleaseImage(img[0] );
```

You can see the documenation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html) and some example [here](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html)